# How to show Android default emoji keyboard on click event ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

I am working on an application. What I want is when user click on emoji icon, Android default emoji keyboard should be shown instead of keyboard. I want my keyboard open like this [image] not like this
[image]

Thanks in advance.